# EXT JS auto scroll container when drag grid column

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have EXT JS grid with width greater then screen width. I have to drag columns to change its order, but when I drag column header to edge of screen - container not scroll. So a need to scroll in manually first and then drad column to right place.
How can I make container autoscroll left or right when I drag column?
I try **containerScroll** with **gridviewdragdrop** plugin but it works only when i drag rows:

```
 viewConfig: {
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                    containerScroll: true
                }, 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after spending some time I found workround. You have to add mousemove event to grid dom after render and control left and right zones and then use scrollBy function of grid view. Here is code:

```
listeners: {
                afterrender:function(me){
                    //console.log(me);
                    me.el.dom.onmousemove=function(ev){

                        if (ev.x>(me.el.dom.clientWidth-50)){
                           // console.log(ev);
                            me.view.scrollBy(50, 0, false);
                        }
                        if (ev.x<50){
                            // console.log(ev);
                            me.view.scrollBy(-50, 0, false);
                        }
                    };
                },
```

Comment: your solutions looks good. but, if you move mouse anywhere on the grid, It will also scroll grid, even if you are not dragging any column.